# Needing to Rotate an ImageView

Tags: android

I have a test Image: Width: 136px and Height: 168px.
It's location on the screen is: x:102 and y:768.
I'm using Animation to rotate this Image:

```
Animation rotate_animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate);
    rotate_animation.reset();
    tile_1.startAnimation(rotate_animation);
```

The associated xml is rotate.xml:

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromDegrees="0"
android:toDegrees="360"
android:toYScale="0.0"
android:pivotX="100%"
android:pivotY="100%"
android:duration="2000" />
```

It rotates, but completely off the screen, and ends up back where it started.
It appears to be rotating around x:0 and y:0.
I want to rotate it in place, around it's center.
I've played around with the numbers in the xml, but it always makes a giant circle.

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the toYScale and setting the pivots to 50%. This way it should rotate from the center of the image

Comment: Same result as before.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code instead in rotate.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="360"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="2000"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/cycle_interpolator"/>
</set>
```

Comment: Same result as before.

Answer (score 0):

```
Found a easy way to do a simple rotation.
My image is tile_1:

tile_1.animate().rotation(360);

HOWEVER, it will only work once unless you set up a Listener first, so full code for a quick 360 degree rotation with a reset to be able to do it again:

 tile_1.animate().setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            tile_1.setRotation(0);

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

        }
    });
    tile_1.animate().rotation(360);
```

// You must reset the rotation to 0. I found out that clearAnimation doesn't work here. When you go to rotate a second time, it does nothing because the Image is already rotated 360, even though it APPEARS to be reset; so you must set the rotation back to zero. Then it works perfectly. Hope this helps someone else :)

You can also add .setDuration here as well, so 'Last Line':
tile_1.animate().rotation(360).setDuration(1000);

One last thing: If you use this in conjunction with TranslateAnimation, and you set the duration on both to the same amount of time, it will move from point XY to point XY while completing 1 rotation. Very smooth looking. Thanks for input from all :)